# PHP private accessor

Tags: php

I made a private variable in my class with a set and get functions but I keep on getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property Car::$make
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpOOP\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpOOP\index.php on line 16

When I change it from `private` to `public` it works fine.

Here is my class:

```
<?php
class Car {
    private $make;
    public $model;
    public $color;

    public function starting(){
        echo "Car Starting";
    }

    public function setMake($make){
        $this->make = $make;
    }
    public function getMake(): string{
        return $this->make;
    }
}
```

And here is where I am creating an instance of the class and trying to use my methods.

```
<body>
    <?php
    include "classes/Car.php";
    $car1->setMake("Honda");
    echo $car1->getMake();
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you point out where line 16 is in your index.php file? Looking at your error message, I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: What exactly is $car1 supposed to be ...? Don't see you creating an instance of the Car class anywhere.

Comment: Is that really all the code? No ommisssions or summarisation?

Comment: You never instantiated `Car`, try `$car1 = new Car();` after the `include`

Comment: _Notice: Undefined variable: car1...
Fatal error:  Call to a member function setMake() on null..._

Answer (score 0):

You are not instantiating your class variable.  You are including your class file, but you then need to instantiate the class

```
<body>
    <?php
    include "classes/Car.php";
    $car1 = new Car();
    $car1->setMake("Honda");
    echo $car1->getMake();
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: If that were the case, it would be complaining that it was access a property on a null object. Since it's complaining about a private property, the class has been instantiated somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed I was progressively learning objects in php.  Was accessing the private variable when it was public.  Then I turned it private to see how that worked.  And my old code that was accessing it was causing the problem not the new stuff with the set and get methods.